# How to store default values for a config file

Tags: java, enums, config

I am currently working on a server program that I want to add a config file to so the user can change certain items such as port, password, etc. I'm stumped on how I should store the default values for when the file is first generated or I need to re-generate it. First I stored them in private static final variables:

```
private static final int PORT = 12345;
```

I then changed to an Enum:

```
 public Enum ConfigDefaults {
     PORT("port", "12345");

     private final String name;
     private final string value;

     public ConfigDefaults(String name, String value)
     {
         this.name = name;
         this.value = value;
     }

     public String getName()
     {
         return name;
     }

     public String getValue()
     {
         return value;
     }
 }
```

I am currently using the Enum however it doesn't seem like the best way to me. What would you recommend as a way to store the defaults for the file?

Comment: What about a `java.util.ListResourceBundle` or any or type or ResourceBundle?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define them statically, as you originally did, you can put them in a ListResourceBundle.

```
package codemasters;

import java.util.*;

public class Configuration extends ListResourceBundle {
     protected Object[][] getContents() {
         return new Object[][] {
             {"port", 8080}, 
             {"host", "codemasters.com"},
             {"protocol", "http"}
         };
     }
 }
```

And then you can use your bundle:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("codemasters.Configuration");
   System.out.println(resource.getObject("port")); //8080
   System.out.println(resource.getString("host")); //codemasters.com
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems you need to solve.

1. How to store the default values (for when you generate the initial configuration stuff).
2. How to store the configuration externally of the application (for example, in a file).

My preferred solutions follow.

### How to store the default values

As defaults, I assume that they will not change frequently and thus can be stored in code.
There are many ways to store values,
I lean towards the simple:

```
public class DefaultValues
{
    public static final String DEFAULT_VALUE_NAME_BLAMMY = "BLAMMY";
    public static final String DEFAULT_VALUE_NAME_SMASHY = "SMASHY";

    private static final String BLAMMY = "blam";
    private static final String SMASHY = "smash";

    // this map is optional and depends on the required complexity of your
    // defaults
    private static final Map<String, String> constants;

    public DefaultValues()
    {
        Map<String, String> initialMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        constants.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_NAME_BLAMMY, BLAMMY);
        constants.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_NAME_SMASHY, SMASHY);

        constants = Collections.unmodifiableMap(initialMap);
    }

    // one way to get the default values; client of this class must know the
    // default value names (exposed as publics from this class).
    public String getDefaultValue(final String defaultValueName)
    {
        return constants.get(defaultValueName);
    }

    // another way to get default values; client does not need to know the
    // default value names (no need for the publics if you use only this
    // technique).
    public Map<String, String> getDefaultValues()
    {
        return constants;
    }
}
```

Instantiate a new DefaultValues() instance only when you need to know the default values.

### How to store the configuration externally of the application

I find that the simplest way to store configuration values is with a property file.
If your configuration is complicated,
you may need something more robust like an XML file.
Properties are well covered in the [Properties JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).
For an XML file,
I suggest a simple SAX parser.
there are many, good examples of SAX parsing on the Internet,
try a google search for "sax parser example".

Answer (score 0):

Use `properties` file to store such things that is configurable and changeable in the life of project.

Its easy to maintain the configuration data in `properties` file **one for each environment**.

You can create different copies of `.properties` file based on environment such as DEV, QA, PROD etc.